# NuGet MSBuild auto-detection finding MSBuild under TeamExplorer?

Tags: msbuild, nuget, visual-studio-2019

I'm building from the command line a visual studio solution and the MSBuild auto-detection procedure is finding msbuild under TeamExplorer which makes the build fail as the needed *.targets files are afterwards not found. I don't have the msbuild under TeamExplorer in PATH env variable and even when running the developer command prompt for VS2019 I only see the msbuild instance under Enterprise (visual studio enterprise edition) in PATH. How/why is the msbuild under TeamExplorer found instead of the one under VS enterprise?

In the logs I see the following when attempting to build a csproj and then it fails picking the wrong msbuild instance

```
Looking for VS 16 installation
MsBuild referenced at: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\TeamExplorer C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise \MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

Comment: Are you using the **Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019** or **Developer PowerShell for VS 2019**?

Comment: what did you mean that msbuild.exe is called from the team explorer? How did you call msbuild.exe? Open CMD and then type `msbuild`? Could you please share more info with us about your steps?

Comment: TeamExplorer gets installed with an instance of msbuild. MSBuild is called as part of a complex gulp-driven build procedure and no specific command prompt is utilized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I investigated in detail the build process and I discovered that msbuild was invoked via powershell (start-process) enumerating the visual studio instances via cmdlets (Get-VSSetupInstance) provided by the VSSetup powershell module and unfortunately it was not expected to find two visual studio instances on the machine (in my case TeamExplorer and VS 2019 Enterprise) and unfortunately the script ended up selecting the first instance returned. I'm now filtering out TeamExplorer and everything works fine. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Quite amazing! Anyway, thanks for sharing your suggestion and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

If you run `msbuild.exe` directly from CMD, you should check your environment variable `PATH` carefully and make sure that you did not specify another wrong version of `msbuild.exe`. And delete the wrong folder which the wrong version of `msbuild.exe` exists.

The right version of msbuild.exe exists under

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe`

I think you should input the path `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin` into the System environment variable **PATH**.

**Also**, according to the principle of `first get first use` of **PATH**, you should place this path at the beginning of **PATH** and test it again.

**In my side**, I only have vs community version and the below is a sample:

[image]

Remember to click **OK**.

**If** it does not work, please provide more info about your steps of calling `msbuild.exe`, whether you can build the project under VS IDE, ......

Comment: I already checked before posting, the msbuild under TeamExplorer is NOT present in either user or system path and in fact even adding the msbuild under Enterprise (VS 2019) to my path env variable it still sometimes detects and uses the wrong one. I'm even considering uninstalling TeamExplorer to stop this nonsense.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. And it seems that the issue is affected by another vs tool. It is quite strange. My suggestion is that please try to add `/p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0` additionally for your build command.  Or try to [repair vs ide and team explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) from `vs_installer`.  And it is not clear why these two tools interfere with each other. I usually use `msbuild xxx\xxx.csproj -t:build -p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0`.

Comment: If it still does not work, please share your msbuild command line with us to troubleshoot the issue:)